# How do i read the data on each line and constructs a new object and put the object into the array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, file

public void loadDatabase(String filename)
{
        UI.println("Reading Database from "+ filename + ".....");

```
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(filename);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            list.add(scan.next());



        }

        scan.close();
        UI.println("Database loaded");
    }
    catch(Exception e){UI.println("Error while reading database file");}



}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What does it do and what errors do you get?

Comment: this part works fine but i have no idea how to read a file from line and make an person object from the line into an array, not sure what the next step is

Comment: So the file contains the member fields of instances of a person class and you want to create one or more person objects with the fields in the file?

Comment: Exactly right! and i have the scanner class written but not sure how to put it into this code

Comment: public Person(Scanner scan){
        this.name = scan.next();
        this.gender = scan.next();
        this.dob = scan.nextInt();
        String m = scan.next();
        if (!m.equals("?")) this.mother = m;
        String f = scan.next();
        if (!f.equals("?")) this.father = f;
    }

Answer (score 0):

not 100% clear your question , but i think you want get data base properties from property file.

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("db.properties")) {
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(reader);
String url = properties.getProperty("db_url");
System.out.println(url);
 } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: not exactly sorry, i wanna get a person from a line and create a person object using arraylists

Comment: i have to create a method that /**
     * Reads the data from the database file into the ArrayList in the db field
     * Ensures that the list in db is empty
     * Reads the data on each line and constructs a Person object,
     *  and puts the Person object into the list
     *   (Should use the second or third Person constructor, either
     *    passing to the constructor a line from the file, or the scanner itself)
     * The method may assume that the database is correctly formatted,
     *  and does not need to do any checking of the input.
     */